# How to detect inner holes in an image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, detection

I want to detect the inner holes in the given image. I used Hough gradient but only the outer holes were detected. Kindly suggest me techniques, how to detect the inner holes.

This is the original image:

[image: 1]

This is the processed image, in which only the outer holes were detected:

[image: 2]

Comment: You may play with the environment like changing backgrounf, lightening etc. if possible. With this sample it seems difficult to handle easily.

Comment: Circle Hought Transform can only find circles.  Most of your inner holes are not circles due to the perspective. what exactly are you interested in? why do you use such poor imaging/lighting?

Comment: @Piglet this is industrial project and breakliner part ...I need to detect the inner and outer holes

Comment: if this is an industrial project why do you work with a  mobile snapshot or webcam?. get some proper equipment. what do you mean by detect? just check wether they are present?

Comment: you might want to look at thresholding + morphological filters (e.g. erode, dilate) to cleanup the binary image then pass that to [`findContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0). Look at the [hierarchy retrieval modes](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html): you should be able to retrieve inner/nested contours (the inner holes in your case). You can look at `minEnclosingCircle` and/or `fitEllipse` to further process contours and filter based on metrics that best describe holes

Comment: @piglet...no the images were taken through basler camera